# Can Vmware ESXI "extended" with Samba support

Tags: vmware, nas, samba, esxi

Well probably this is a NO question but because you never know i thought i would give it a try.
I would like the Vmware ESXI host to have also Samba support in order to serve as NAS to my infrastructure, is this somehow , in any way possible ?

Comment: Why not just run it in a VM instead?

Comment: For minimum - minimum resource consumption